# I want to getText from html source code

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath

HTML:-

```
<div class="row">

<div id="tl-detail-container-left" class="col-md-6">

<div class="section-title">ETL Details</div>

<ul class="info-display-cell-ltl entity-item">

<li>

<span class="vline"></span>

<div class="entity-value" title="darsht">Name: darsht</div>

</li>
```

What I have done:

```
WebElement path=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/ul/li[1]");
String str= path.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='entity-value']")). get Text();
System.out.println(str);
```

Please help me with the code to get `dynamic Text` 
(ex: Omarjiti) from html.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, use the [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library.

Comment: How does this apply to the question above?

Answer (score 0):

your xpath should be optimized. 
Other thing you are perfoming `findElement` two times. Once you done with `findElement` then just use it's property.

```
 WebElement webelement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='vline']/div");
String str= webelement.getText();
```

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) for detailed on `xpath`.